# how can I find supremum in n?

Tags: calculus

I have $$f_n(x)=\begin{cases} 
      \frac{1}{n} & |x|\leq n, \\ 0 & |x|>n .
   \end{cases}$$
and I know that the result is
$$
\sup_n|f_n(x)|=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{m} & |x|\in (m-1,m],m=1,2,...\\                                                      0 & x=0 \end{cases}
$$
but how can I arrive to this ? Can you please do all calculations?

Comment: $\sup_n|f_n(x)|$ cannot depend on $n$.

Comment: @geetha290krm yes ou are right , maybe I have copied a wrong result . maybe there should be 1/x  . But I still don't know how to calculate

Comment: You should write $\sup_n|f_n(x)|=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{|x|} & |x|\in (m-1,m] , m=1,2,... \\                                                      0 & x=0 \end{cases}
$

Comment: @geetha290krm ok I will copy

Comment: Sorry. It should be $\sup_n|f_n(x)|=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{m} & |x|\in (m-1,m] , m=1,2,... \\                                                      0 & x=0 \end{cases}
$

Comment: @geetha290krm ok

Comment: You have to show some effort on your part. Can you show LHS $\le $ RHS?

Comment: @geetha290krm no , If I was able to do that I would not asked.  And wh I should show an inequality ? I mean you  are doing specific passagges if you show me the passages I can think about it

Comment: Hint: For every $x$ there is a unique $m$ such that $|x|\in (m-1,m]$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Ok i have made a picture and now is clear the result . But if I want to make a calculus is it possible ?This is my question , like for finding derivatives , there are calculus rules